# Jboss Fuse migration from 6.3 to Fuse 7

Tags: apache-camel, jboss7.x, jbossfuse

I am planning to migrate from Fuse jboss-fuse-6.3.0.redhat-329 to Fuse 7. I am using camel version 2.17.0.redhat-630329. Can anyone please guide me on the steps and issues faced while migrating?

Comment: I have recently migrated 6.3 to 7.7 and have not faced any issues, do you have any specific concern?

Comment: We are using microservices design pattern with several containers on fabric. I have almost 29 containers in my fabric. Will it be an issue? Also if you can please share the migration link, it would be great.

Comment: What feature of fabric are you using? just the profiles for deployment or something else like http/jms-proxy or camel master endpoints?

Comment: There are migration guides between each Fuse release. they are covering most common stuffto look at. For instance, from 6.x to 7.0: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_fuse/7.0/html/migration_guide/index or the latest 7.6 to 7.7 https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_fuse/7.7/html/migration_guide/index

Comment: @Valdar I am using basic camel features and some cxf jars for exposing services. I hope its going to be ok

Comment: @fg78nc Were you using fabric earlier?

Comment: @AllamKumar No, we are not using fabric8.

Answer (score 4):

First of all its good that you plan to upgrade from Fuse 6.3 to 7.x.
I recommend to upgrade to the latest Fuse 7.7 release in order to benefit from additional bug fixes, CVE fixes and enhancements.

Your migration to Fuse 7 will upgrade Camel from 2.17 to 2.21.
I suggest you have a read over the Fuse 7.0 migration guide [1], which specifically covers the migration from Fuse 6.3 to 7.

Then you may also want to peak at the migration guide of the specific 7.x release that you are upgrading to, for 7.7 it will be [2].
Please also check for deprecated components...

In terms of Camel, it will depend on the Camel components used if there are any code changes needed or not. For the vast majority of components no changes should be required.

Potentially you only need to recompile your application against the latest Fuse 7 BOM and redeploy the application (in case of Karaf of EAP runtime).

I hope this helps as a starting point.

[1] https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_fuse/7.0/html/migration_guide/index

[2] https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_fuse/7.7/html/migration_guide/index

Comment: Thanks. I will go through them.

Answer (score 0):

Overall performance between Fuse 6 and 7 should roughly be similar.
However in order to give any meaningful reply one would need to understand what specific components of Fuse or Camel you use in order to measure performance and what processing is performed and how you measure performance.
There won't be a quick answer here and if you have support for Red Hat Fuse, it would be best to open a support ticket with Red Hat.